# Solidus / Spree Override not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

I'm trying to change the homepage product listing. 
So i'm trying to override the file in this path:

https://github.com/solidusio/solidus/blob/master/frontend/app/views/spree/shared/_products.html.erb

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/shared/products',
                 :replace_contents => "li#product_",
                 :name => "product_new",
                 :text => "text")
```

However this code makes absolutely 0 change on the homepage.

The file in which this override is in is called product_override.rb and is in app/overrides

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this code with a fresh install of Solidus and it worked.
Note that I have added an underscore before "products" in `:virtual_path => 'spree/shared/_products'`. Also, I changed the selector to "li".

```
Deface::Override.new(:virtual_path => 'spree/shared/_products',
             :insert_after => "li",
             :name => "product_new",
             :text => "Override is working")
```